# Using dot or "source" while calling another script - what is the difference?

Tags: bash, dot-source

Let's take a little example:

```
$ cat source.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm file source-1"

. source-2.sh
```

And:

```
$ cat source-2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm file source-2"
```

Now run:

```
$ ./source.sh
I'm file source-1
I'm file source-2
```

If I'll change the call of the second file in first:

```
$ cat source.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm file source-1"

source source-2.sh
```

It will have the same effect as using `dot`.

What is difference between these methods?

Comment: i also use `bash source-2.sh` sometimes. but if the script just runs `ls` then using `bash source-2.sh` doesn't show shell text colours like the others, and if the script tries to run a missing file then `bash source-2.sh` doesn't provide suggestions on what it thinks you meant to run. and if the script contains `set -e` and i run it with `. source-2.sh` or `source source-2.sh` then it will run the file and crash with suggestions but also crash the server i'm running it on but does crash the server if i used `bash source-2.sh` instead. but to run `bash source-2.sh`, `bash` needs be installed

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There is no difference.

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> `source`
>
> ```
> source filename
>
> A synonym for . (see Bourne Shell Builtins).
> ```

Comment: Well, it's not true that there is no difference. E.g. the dot is shorter! :^)

Comment: If we're talking ergonomics, the dot is much less readable and harder for newbies to search for

Answer (score 129):

The only difference is in portability.

`.` is the POSIX-standard command for executing commands from a file; `source` is a more-readable synonym provided by Bash and some other shells. Bash itself, however, makes no distinction between the two.

Comment: Is it just me or does using `source` in `bash --version` `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` produce a different behaviour than `.` in weird cases (such as doing it from a function). -- my experience is that `source` export variables more reliably than `.` -- (also, bash differentiate `.` from `source` when re-reading the code via `declare -f`)

Comment: @MathieuCAROFF could you paste a simple script example? I am running the exact same bash version as you