# Does the dot command behave uniformly across different shells?

Tags: shell, sh, dot-source

You can use the `.` command to execute commands from a shell script as if they were in the calling shell script itself.

If I use the ***dot*** command in my shell scripts, will it behave similarly across different shell interpreters?

PLEASE Note: I'm **not asking** about the difference between the `.` command and the `source` command. If that's what you want to learn, please see this other question: [Using dot or "source" while calling another script - what is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094271/using-dot-or-source-while-calling-another-script-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: See also: [Unix.SE: Source vs . why different behaviour?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/309768/source-vs-why-different-behaviour)

Comment: See also: [What is the difference between '.' and 'source' in shells?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58514/what-is-the-difference-between-and-source-in-shells). This one has the most comprehensive answer, by the always exhaustive Stéphane Chazelas.

Comment: It will behave similarly across all shells that conform to whatever standard defines the expected behavior.  A commonly accepted standard is that defined at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18.  Many shells do not conform to that standard unless you provide specific directions.  (eg `bash --posix`, or invoking bash with the name `sh`).

Comment: Personally, I find the "look in PATH for not-necessarily-executable files" is surprising behaviour (even [just this morning](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/658671/4667)) but that's specified by POSIX, and at least dash, bash, ksh and zsh all work that way

Answer (score 0):

Under certain simple shells, the dot operator **doesn't behave as expected**:

```
$ /bin/sh --help
BusyBox v1.32.1 () multi-call binary.

$ cat /tmp/dot-sh.sh
#!/bin/sh
. xxx || echo "dot worked as expected"

$ /tmp/dot-sh.sh
/tmp/dot-sh.sh: 2: .: xxx: not found
```

To test the example above, you can:

```
docker run --rm -it alpine sh
```

But under `/bin/bash`, the dot operator **does** behave as expected:

```
$ cat /tmp/dot-bash.sh
#!/bin/bash
. xxx || echo "dot worked as expected"

$ /tmp/dot-bash.sh
/tmp/dot-bash.sh: line 2: xxx: No such file or directory
dot worked as expected
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what the difference is exactly and why bash's behavior is expected?

Comment: I disagree.  Aborting is the expected behavior.  Bash's behavior is non-standard, unexpected, and bizarre.

Comment: The [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) says "If no readable file is found, a non-interactive shell shall abort; an interactive shell shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, but this condition shall not be considered a syntax error." -- `bash --posix dot-bash.sh` does indeed abort.

Comment: I'm not sure I would consider `bash` bizarre, but it's definitely non-standard. (I didn't expect the shell to abort, but I was unaware of the distinction that POSIX `.` makes between interactive and non-interactive shells.)